# How can update the statement finding the day with the highest value and second highest value

Tags: sql

I need to change the Yes/No column where the day column has its highest value and second highest value.

Id menu(INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)    ;      Day(INT NULL)   ;   YES/NO(BIT NUL)
100       ;                 1   ;       1
101         ;           2   ;       0
102         ;           3   ;       1
103         ;           4   ;       0
104         ;           5   ;       0

The result I should get is
Id menu(INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)   ;   Day(INT NULL)   ;   YES/NO(BIT NUL)
100     ;               1       ;   1
101         ;           2       ;   0
102         ;           3       ;   1
103         ;           4       ;   1
104             ;       5       ;   1

I can change the line with 
UPDATE Menu SET YES/NO = 1 WHERE DAY = 4

But since the days will continue rising that means I have to know which is the highest day before writing the statement. How can update the statement finding the day with the highest value and second highest value
I tried UPDATE Menu SET YES/NO = 1 WHERE MAX(day)

Comment: try `UPDATE menu SET yes_no=1 WHERE day=MAX(day) OR day=(MAX(day)-1);` or if there not sequential and you don't know the second max will be one under the max then `UPDATE menu SET yes_no=1 WHERE day=MAX(day) OR day=(SELECT MAX(day) FROM menu WHERE day<MAX(day));`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I don't see from your description how you get a 0 in the row for ID = 101; actually, nor for 100 or 102.  The 'highest two values in the day column' are 4 and 5, so all the earlier values (1, 2, 3) should have the yes/no bit set to No, shouldn't they?

Answer (score 0):

Test Driven Query Design (TDQD) to the rescue once more.

#### Find the maximum day value

```
SELECT MAX(day) FROM Menu
```

#### Find the second maximum day value

```
SELECT MAX(day)
  FROM Menu
 WHERE day != (SELECT MAX(day) FROM Menu)
```

The second maximum day is the biggest day value that is not the maximum day value.

#### Select the rows not containing the second maximum or maximum day value

```
SELECT *
  FROM Menu
 WHERE Day < (SELECT MAX(day)
                FROM Menu
               WHERE day != (SELECT MAX(day) FROM Menu)
             )
```

These are the rows where the Yes/No bit needs to be set to zero.

#### Select the rows containing the second maximum or maximum day value

```
SELECT *
  FROM Menu
 WHERE Day >= (SELECT MAX(day)
                 FROM Menu
                WHERE day != (SELECT MAX(day) FROM Menu)
              )
```

These are the rows where the Yes/No bit needs to be set to one.

#### Update the two sets of rows

Clearly, you can replace the `SELECT *` with `UPDATE Menu SET Yes_No = 0` (or `1`) for the two sets of data.  You probably can combine the two into a single operation, if your DBMS allows you to select from the table you are updating (not all DBMS do that):

```
UPDATE Menu
   SET Yes_No = (CASE WHEN day < (SELECT MAX(day) FROM Menu
                                   WHERE day != (SELECT MAX(day) FROM Menu))
                      THEN 0
                      ELSE 1 END)
```